# get 6 different value from an array in php

Tags: php

i have an array value like bellow

```
$arr=array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38');
```

and i want get all different value from this array 
ex

```
$data=array(
            array('05','01',04,06,09,02),array('07','01',04,06,09,02)........
)
```

and all array value can not duplicate

```
more example 
$arr=array(1,2,3,4,5);
result with 2 array value
$result=array(
       array(1,2),array(2,3),array(1,3),array(3,4),array(1,4),array(2,4),array(4,5),array(2,5),array(3,5),array(1,5)
)
```

Comment: Please add more detail, it's unclear what you are trying to access.

Comment: i want get random array $arr to 6 value array and different value. and all value in 6 value array must not duplicate value

Comment: it's more algorithm than programming.

Answer (score -1):

Use [shuffle](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and [array_chunk](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
<?php

shuffle($arr);
$split = array_chunk($arr, 6);
```

Comment: same issue, how to get all, how to avoid pairs duplicate?